# Remove background from images with PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, png, gd, gif

I'm doing page similar to this:
http://stylistki.pl/stworz-zestaw/
It's in polish language, users can add images, but im wondering how the script is cutting the background... I'd like to do same thing on my page. But my effect in GD its not good. Check it:
http://stylopedia.paszek-inc.waw.pl/w_szafa/getImage.php
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

> but im wondering how the script is cutting the background...

It's not. It's just white background which doesn't matter if container is also white.

Comment: Look at this: http://stylistki.pl/editimg.php?did=1276&iid=859a917986f2f5c3140573fd204129a9s10 and this: http://stylistki.pl/editimg.php?did=1276&iid=859a917986f2f5c3140573fd204129a9s10&bg . I see the difference...